# React Relay: Adding data to edges

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I'll first introduce my application: simple voting app where users can create and vote on polls. Simple.
Currently my graphql schema consists of user type, poll type and vote type, where the user and poll have one-to-many relation to its votes, using relay connection. 
The vote type contains, along with reference to its voter and poll, it's timestamp and the actual vote value.

Now, to my understanding, one of the advanges of using connections over regulations graphql lists is the ability to store data on the edge (in addition to pagination and more...).
How could I do that?

If it is indeed possible, my plan is to get rid of the vote type, connect the user and his voted polls directly via connections, and storing the vote value and it's timestamp on the connecting edge.

If it's important, the connection between the voter and his polls should be bidirectional,  i.e. each user is connected to his voted polls, and each poll is connected to its voters.

Comment: "If it's important, the connection between the voter and his polls should be bidirectional, i.e. each user is connected to his voted polls, and each poll is connected to its voters." — Yes, it does seem pretty important. Edges are specific to a connection, and you have two connections here, so need distinct edges for each. Where is the source of truth about the voter-vote-poll relationship to reside if there are two of them?

Comment: I see what you're saying, I just saw the vote type as an extra mediator, since I already have connection, but you're probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably better modeled using a separate `Vote` entity as described in [Michael Paris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38003827/2103996), however, to address the more general question of "how do I define additional fields on an edge?", note that you can pass `edgeFields` into the `connectionDefinitions` function [in the graphql-relay module](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/f1dfe502cfeccf80deadce3ce2cfde618a8acb36/src/connection/connection.js#L105).

There's an example [in the test suite](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/f1dfe502cfeccf80deadce3ce2cfde618a8acb36/src/connection/__tests__/connection.js#L64-L80):

```
var {connectionType: friendConnection} = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'Friend',
  nodeType: userType,
  resolveNode: edge => allUsers[edge.node],
  edgeFields: () => ({
    friendshipTime: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: () => 'Yesterday'
    }
  }),
  connectionFields: () => ({
    totalCount: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: () => allUsers.length - 1
    }
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are really close to having what you want already. I would argue that using the Vote type as the middleman between a User and a Poll is a good solution. Doing it this way would allow you to issue queries that look something like this:

```js
// Direction 1: User -> Vote -> Poll
query GetUser($id: "abc") {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    username
    votes(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          value
          poll {
            name
          }
        }
        cursor
      }
    }
  }
}

// Direction 2: Poll -> Vote -> User
query GetPoll($id: "xyz") {
  getPoll(id: $id) {
    name
    votes(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          value
          user {
            username
          }
        }
        cursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, your Vote type is the entity that stores the information along the edge. You are correct that one advantage of Connections over Lists is that you can store information along the edge, but I would say that the bigger benefit is the ability to paginate through large sets of objects.

To implement this on a server, you will have to write custom resolve methods for your the Connection fields on User and Poll (i.e. the 'votes' fields in the example above). Depending on how you store your data this will change but here is some pseudo code for an idea.

```js
type Vote {
  value: String,
  poll: Poll, // Both poll & user would have resolve functions to grab their respective object.
  user: User
}

type VoteEdge {
  node: Vote,
  cursor: String // an opaque cursor used in the 'before' & 'after' pagination args
}

type PageInfo {
  hasNextPage: Boolean,
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean
}

type VotesConnectionPayload {
  edges: [VoteEdge],
  pageInfo: PageInfo
}

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
      description: "A unique identifier."
    },
    username: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      description: "A username",
    },
    votes: {
      type: VotesConnectionPayload,
      description: "A paginated set of the user's votes",
      args: { // pagination args
        first: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        },
        after: {
          type: GraphQLString
        },
        last: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        },
        before: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      }
      resolve: (parent, paginationArgs, ctxt) => {

        // You can pass a reference to your data source in the ctxt.
        const db = ctxt.db;

        // Go get the full set of votes for my user. Preferably this returns a cursor
        // to the set so you don't pull everything over the network
        return db.getVotesForUser(parent.id).then(votes => {

          // Assume we have a pagination function that applies the pagination args
          // See https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm for more details
          return paginate(votes, paginationArgs);

        }).then((paginatedVotes, pageInfo) => {

          // Format the votes as a connection payload.
          const edges = paginatedVotes.map(vote => {

            // There are many ways to handle cursors but lets assume
            // we have a magic function that gets one.
            return {
              cursor: getCursor(vote),
              node: vote
            }

          });

          return {
            edges: edges,
            pageInfo: pageInfo
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
});
```

You would have to do something similarly in your Poll type for the reverse direction. To add object to the connection all you would need to do is create a Vote object that points to the correct User and Post. The db.getVotesForUser() method should be smart enough to realize this is a One-To-Many Connection and can then pull the correct objects.

Creating a standard way of handling connections can be a daunting task, but fortunately there are some services that can help you get started using GraphQL without having to implement all backend logic yourself. I work for one such service https://scaphold.io and would be happy to talk this solution through further with you if you're interested!

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer!   But since the edges already take the role of the middleman,  I thought it will be better to get rid of the vote type, and just paginate voters which are users, and the vote value will be stored on the connecting edge, instead of having the useless vote type. Wouldn't you agree this should be better?

Comment: I wanna thank you again for your answer, I'm gonna mark wincent's as the answer since this is what I essentially asked, but you're answer is very helpful, appreciate it!

Comment: Doesn't this approach massively overfetch data? We only want something like first:10. But the query size to the approach you give unlimited..